# How to install my app symfony 2.7 in a server VPS withour port in the url

Tags: php, symfony

What is the procedure to install my app symfony 2.7 in ubuntu VPS with a domain for example www.myapp.com without a port

the documentarion is this:
$ cd my_project_name/
$ php app/console server:run
Then, open your browser and access the http://localhost:8000/app/example URL to see the Welcome page of Symfony:

but, they dont say nothing about how it is installed on a server such as apache for example, width a virtualhost

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

**app/console server:run** command for only development purpose

You need to configure web server for this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Here are my hosts and virtualhost files: http://blog.digi-solution.com/?page_id=310 i put everything like web server configuration instructions and it does not work! :(, when go to http://myapp.symfony.local/, this is a result: Not Found The requested URL /app.php was not found on this server. if change the root directory in my virtualhost to include the web folder, does not work either, the app.php is execute but symfony not run, no one who has made this publication on a server or on localhost?

Comment: first of all you need to include web folder to your virtual host, also did you check your error log? what does it say? did you give writing permission to app/logs and app/cache folders?

Comment: Excelent my friend, only add web to the root directory on my virtualhosts and clean the cache, them http://myapp.symfony.local/app_dev.php with the debugg bar and http://myapp.symfony.local/ normal way, work now just fine!  thank you very much!